# ORDER BY one col but if the value is the same ORDER by another col

Tags: mysql

I'm currently ORDERing my data by total (the column is datatype DECIMAL 10,2) which is fine, however if the total is the same then it needs to be ORDERED by epoch ASC so oldest dated totals (with my epoch timestamp) are displayed first if they're the same amount. Current mysql query:

```
SELECT email, total, epoch FROM data ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: `ORDER BY total DESC, Epoch ASC`

Comment: how embarrassing thanks

Comment: @MartinSmith, no need of specifying `ASC` since that's default

Comment: @Rahul No need not to specify it either.

Comment: @MartinSmith, didn't got you but saying this is way enough `ORDER BY total DESC, Epoch`

Comment: @Rahul he is saying the only benefit to omitting `ASC` is saving yourself a few key presses at the expense of clarity.

Comment: @Uueerdo, what clarity you are talking about? MySQL docs or spec clearly says the same ... then what more clarity required?

Comment: @Rahul clarity of intent, and readability. Precedence of AND and OR are specified as well, that does not mean "A AND B OR C AND D" is easy to read.

Comment: @uueerdo, that's a different thing all together